# Python While Loop Function Multiple Conditions

Tags: python, function, while-loop, multiple-conditions

I am trying to create a function  that takes two words and returns them if conditions are met. Word 1 has to be a certain number of characters, word 2 has to begin with a certain letter. I can get it to work with one condition but am confused when I have to meet two. This is what I have so far. Example below

```
Enter a 4 letter word: two
Enter a 4 letter word: wall
Enter a word starting with B: apple
Enter a word starting with B: boxes
['wall', 'boxes']
```

```
    def twoWords(lenLet, strtLet):
    input1 = str(input("Enter a word that is 4 letters long: "))
    while len(input1) != 4:
        input1 = str(input("Enter a word that is 4 letters long: "))
        if len(input1) == 4:
            break
    input2 = str(input("Enter a word that begins with b: "))
    while firstletter(input2) != 'b' or 'B':
        input2 = str(input("Enter a word that begins with b: "))
        if firstletter(input2) == 'b' or 'B':
            break
    return input1 and input2

print(twoWords()
```

Comment: `firstletter(input2) != 'b' or 'B'` doesn't work.  Do `firstletter(input2).lower() != 'b'`.

Answer (score 0):

You were on the right track, but you can't do `firstletters(input) == 'b' or 'B'`. What you could to is transform to lower case and then check against 'b' using `input2[0].lower() != 'b'` or you could use `input2[0] not in ('b', 'B')` to check for both.

A side note: You don't need to cast the result of `input()` to `str` as it already is a `str`. And I am not sure what you want to return but `input1 and input2` does not make much sense. If you want to return both words (in a [tuple](https://www.w3schools.com/python/python_tuples.asp)) use `return (input1, input2)`. If you just want to say that the input was correct you could use `return True`. The return statement will only be reached if both words meet your conditions otherwise your program will be in an infinite loop.

Please note, that I have replaced your `firstletters()` function with `input[0]` which works for the first character. If you want to check for a couple of characters you could also use [`str.startswith()`](https://www.tutorialspoint.com/python/string_startswith.htm).

```py
def twoWords(lenLet, strtLet):
    # no need to cast to str, input always returns a str
    input1 = input(f"Enter a word that is {lenLet} letters long: ")
    while len(input1) != 4:
        input1 = input(f"Try again. Enter a word that is {lenLet} letters long: ")
        if len(input1) == 4:
            break
    input2 = input(f"Enter a word that begins with {strtLet}: ")
    while input2[0].lower() != 'b':
        input2 = input(f"Try again. Enter a word that begins with {strtLet}: ")
        if input2[0].lower() == 'b':
            break
    # you will be stuck in an infinite loop as long as the conditions are not met
    # only when the conditions are met you will arrive here so you can just return true
    return True

print(twoWords(4, "b"))
```